# mongoose $push pushes empty object in loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to handle POST request, after which some info should be added to multiple docs, but `$push` doesn't seem to work - it pushes an empty object, $set on the other hand works great.  I've tried for loop, Q and now async, but something still doesn't work.

**Schema:**

```
var MeasurementSchema = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  t: Number,
  v: Number
});

var SensorSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  unit: String,
  measurements: [ MeasurementSchema ]
});
```

**POST request:**

```
{
    "timestamp": 100000,
    "measurements": [
        ["1/1/1", 10, "temperature"],
        ["1/1/2", 20, "sunny"],
        ["1/1/3", 30, "foo"],
        ["1/1/4", 110, "bar"]
    ]
}
```

**POST handling:**

```
 .post(function(req, res) {
    var r = req.body;
    var i = 0;

    async.whilst(
        function() { return i < r.measurements.length; },
        function(callback) {
            Sensor.findByIdAndUpdate(
                r.measurements[i][0],
                {
                    $push: { measurements: { t: r.timestamp, v: r.measurements[i][1] } },
                    $set: { unit: r.measurements[i][2] }
                },
                { upsert: true, new: true, safe: true },
                function (err, result) {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                    i++;
                    callback(err,result);
                }
            ); 
        },
        function(err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        }

    );
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Can you comment your error output.

Comment: @MathankumarK I don't recieve any errors - in database I've got this:
```
{
 "_id" : "1/1/1",
 "__v" : 0,
 "measurements" : [
  {
   
  }
 ],
 "unit" : "temperature"
}

```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a simple mistake in the `$push` query.

`measurement` is an array of `objects` with fields `t` and `v` , currently you are trying to `push` `t` and `v` individually, but not as a single `object`, just enclose them in `{}`, and it should work fine.

**Replace :**

```
$push: { measurements: { t: r.timestamp, v: r.measurements[i][1] } },
```

**with :**

```
$push: { measurements: { { t: r.timestamp, v: r.measurements[i][1] } } },
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Shouldnt outer object have key?

Comment: Anyway, I tried your way and it didn't work, however when I get back to my version... it did! I have no idea what happened, but thanks :p